# A simple string pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

For the code given below, why is the output "This is the string" instead of the address of the first character in the string, 'T'?

```
int main()
{
    char myString[] = "This is a string";
    char *ptr = &myString[0];
    cout << ptr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Output is to be clicked above.

Comment: Because `&myString[0]` is identical to `myString`, by definition.

Comment: `operator<<` for `char *` prints a string.

Answer (score 1):

> why is the output "This is the string" instead of the address of the first character in the string, `'T'`?

There is an `operato<<` overload whose LHS is a `std::ostream` and the RHS is `char const*`. This function prints the string.

If you want to print the address of `'T'`, you can cast the pointer to a `void*`.

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(ptr) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *ptr = &myString[0];
```

Means make `ptr` point to the first character of `myString`.  Then`cout` has an overload of `<<` that takes a `char *` and will print what it points to and and the preceding elements until it reaches an `'\0'`

If you want to print the address of the array then you need to convert the pointer to something else like a `void*` first and then print:

```
cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptr) << endl;
```

Comment: _....char * and will print what it points to and and the preceding elements until it reaches an '\0'_. Did you mean _following elements_ instead of _preceding elements_?